# How to successfully connect to Foxpro database files using SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server-2014, linked-server, foxpro

I am trying to connect Foxpro (`.dbf`) files to a SQL Server 2014 database. I tried to use linked server option however unable to find the oledb provider enabled for Foxpro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VFP OLEDB provider can be freely [downloaded from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839) but it is only available for 32 bits.

There is no 64-bit OLEDB provider for VFP, and hence you can only use Fox data directly in 32-bit instances of MS SQL Server. For a 64-bit server you'd basically have to link to a separate 32-bit instance of SQL Server in which the Fox DBFs are linked via the OLEDB provider.

This sort of works, and we've been using something like this in production for years (with SQL Server 2014). However, it is a supremely awkward setup that tends to leak little TMP files by the thousands, at least in connection with Reporting Services. On the whole you might be better off with solutions that don't involve DBF access from within SQL Server...

*P.S.: whenever I can get away with it, I use Fox to keep the data in SQL Server up to date instead of linking DBFs. With `SQLEXEC()` this is much less painful than using e.g. C# to access data, and performance is only limited by your Fox data massaging skills. For bulk upload of data, Fox can blast out CSVs and then run sqlcmd/bcp on them (or again `SQLEXEC()`, as the case may be).*